# Bootstrap tooltip from dynamic HTML not working

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, tooltip

I have an `HTML` page that part of it is generated using `HTML` injection from a `typescript` `angularjs` controller using `$sce` and `ng-bind-html`.
My problem is that the `bootstrap` tooltip style isn't applied and I only get the simple built in yellow tooltip.
My controller function that generates the HTML (not sure if it's relevant but note the comment next to the `console.log` section):

```
public renderHtml = () => {
this.test = '<span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>';
console.log(this.test); // this line is logged 6 times with the same value on each page refresh

return this.$sce.trustAsHtml(this.test);
}
```

The HTML (I've added the exact same HTML snippet directly to the page and it works fine):

```
<!--bootstrap tooltip doesn't show-->
<div class="row margin-25" ng-bind-html="cdc.renderHtml()"></div>

<div>
<!--bootstrap tooltip works-->
<span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>
</div>
```

Here is the outcome (not working on left):
[image: tooltips]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/javascript/#tooltips):

> *Opt-in functionality*
>
> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning **you must initialize them yourself**.

Example with your approach on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uy4unj4/):

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($sce) {
    this.renderHTML = () => {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml('<span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>');
    };
  });
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span').tooltip();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-bind-html="vm.renderHTML()"></div>
    <span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Better [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/am8mg9nv/1/) is use directive:

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($sce) {})
  .directive("title", function($timeout) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $(element).tooltip()
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div>
      <span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>
    </div>
    <span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at your first solution, It only worked for me after adding a `setTimeout` to the `document ready` function since otherwise it happened after the call to the `renderHTML` function. I'll have to read a little about how to setup a directive using `TypeScript` in order to implement your second approach. Thank you!

Comment: No need use `TypeScript` for implement directive.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap works with jQuery, meaning all interaction is called upon `document.ready`, when you add new content, jQuery doesn't know how to use this new content. 
There is a project that implements bootstrap the angular way: [ng-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Instead of writing HTML in your code to add to the page, you should work using [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) or [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). 
I would recommend following the [free course by codeschool](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro), it explains how to use them, and why this is the *angular way*.

To simply get your tooltip to work, without doing it more in the angular way:

```js
public renderHtml = () => {
  this.test = '<span style="text-decoration:underline" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">my team</span>';
  console.log(this.test); // this line is logged 6 times with the same value on each page refresh
  
  $timeout(function() {
    angular.element('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); // if you've added jQuery, angular.element simply uses jQuery
  }, 0); // timeout 0 means it'll run in the next $digest cycle.

  return this.$sce.trustAsHtml(this.test);
}
```